# save os.walk() in variable

Tags: python, os.walk

Can I somehow save the output of `os.walk()` in variables ? I tried
`basepath, directories, files = os.walk(path)`
but it didn't work. I want to proceed the files of the directory and one specific subdirectory. is this somehow possible ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.walk()` returns a generator that will successively return *all* the tree of files/directories from the initial path it started on. If you only want to process the files in a directory and one specific subdirectory you should use a mix of `os.listdir()` and a mixture of `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.isdir()` to get what you want.

Something like this:

```
def files_and_subdirectories(root_path):
    files = []
    directories = []
    for f in os.listdir(root_path):
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            files.append(f)
        elif os.path.isdir(f):
            directories.append(f)
    return directories, files
```

And use it like so:

```
directories,files = files_and_subdirectories(path)
```

Comment: thats a wonderful solution, i'll expand it by listing the subdirectory and i have what i want
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I want to proceed the files of the directory and one specific
>   subdirectory. is this somehow possible ?

If that's all you want then simply try

```
[e for e in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(e)] + os.listdir(special_dir)
```